# Get point from webpage VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, browser

How can I get the point from a webpage?
Let's say I want to click on a textbox from a site, because it's easier than searching all the tag names and stuff. So...when click on a button I can go to the webbrowser and get the point of that textbox (e.g 400,210), but I want to get the point to work for the webbrowser not matter what size it is. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to write a screen scraper. I suggest you look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Not exactly...it's more like a program that makes scripts for one of my other programs, but It would be very annoying to make a screenshot of the whole website then get the point where the textbox is located at manually

Comment: Why can't you use javascript? document.GetElementById('mytextbox') is ideally suited to this (IMHO).

Comment: I don't know so much about sites but I'm not sure if every site has "clean" textboxes which are easy to manipulate like this:
WebBrowser1.Document.All("user").InvokeMember("click")